Render a multiband image as multiband color/ Generate and show a RGB image from multiband image
I have a multiband image which I need to render as a mutiband color image with all the defaut values. Now, in the UI of QGIS, I can do it. But in Python console, I can not do it as the images are coming as crazy. One of the reson might be the stretching and min max normalization. How can I add these in my current Python code?
This is the code I have currently.
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject, QgsMultiBandColorRenderer

def apply_multiband_color_renderer(raster_path):
    # Load the raster layer
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(raster_path, "Multiband Image")
    if not raster_layer.isValid():
        print("Failed to load the raster layer!")
        return
    
    # Add raster layer to the project
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer)

    # Define the band indices for RGB
    red_band = 3
    green_band = 2
    blue_band = 1

    # Create a multiband color renderer
    renderer = QgsMultiBandColorRenderer(raster_layer.dataProvider(), red_band, green_band, blue_band)

    # Apply the renderer to the layer
    raster_layer.setRenderer(renderer)
    raster_layer.triggerRepaint()

# Path to your multiband raster file
path_to_raster = r'C:\Users\User\Documents\ARSI\ImagesForRoni_2024319\ImagesForRoni_2024319\ProvidenceRI\20210717_151344_1038_TOAR.tif'

apply_multiband_color_renderer(path_to_raster)


I want the exact thing when I select this exact options in QGIS.

The output image is coming like this.

I also have some zero values, which I want to treat as no data.
My goal is to load a multiband image and show it as a RGB image from RGB bands.
